# Print Screen doesn't work

Tags: screenshot

Print screen key does work in ubuntu 12.4.
downloaded an app called screenshot and that works great.
but would like to know why the print screen key is disabled

Comment: What is the key assignment in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Screenshots -> Take a screenshot?